# homomorphism from decomposition group to Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces, ideals

Let K be a number field that is Galois over $\Bbb Q$ with group $G = Gal(K/\Bbb Q)$. Fix a prime $\mathfrak p ⊂ \mathcal O_K$ lying over $p ∈ \Bbb Z$.Let $D_{\mathfrak p}$ be its decomposition group.

Studying Stein's Algebraic Number Theory book, I came across this sentence:
[image]

I don't see why it is the case, any reference or insights about this homomorphism?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The question seems to have nothing to do with the title.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the title.

Comment: $D_\mathfrak{p}$ is defined as the subgroup of $Aut(O_K)$ such that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{p}$ so its elements are well-defined on the quotient $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$ by $\sigma(a+\mathfrak{p}) = \sigma(a)+\sigma(\mathfrak{p})=\sigma(a)+\mathfrak{p}\in O_K/\mathfrak{p}$.